# Font issue on jasper reports

Tags: java, tomcat, fonts, jasper-reports

I have an application on tomcat that after the update of the tomcat version when it generate jasper reports starts to display this logs:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
at sun.font.ExtendedTextSourceLabel.createCharinfo(ExtendedTextSourceLabel.java:608)
at sun.font.ExtendedTextSourceLabel.getCharinfo(ExtendedTextSourceLabel.java:508)
at sun.font.ExtendedTextSourceLabel.getLineBreakIndex(ExtendedTextSourceLabel.java:454)
at java.awt.font.TextMeasurer.calcLineBreak(TextMeasurer.java:325)
at java.awt.font.TextMeasurer.getLineBreakIndex(TextMeasurer.java:561)
at java.awt.font.LineBreakMeasurer.nextOffset(LineBreakMeasurer.java:358)
at java.awt.font.LineBreakMeasurer.nextLayout(LineBreakMeasurer.java:440)
at java.awt.font.LineBreakMeasurer.nextLayout(LineBreakMeasurer.java:413)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.TextMeasurer.renderNextLine(TextMeasurer.java:611)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.TextMeasurer.renderParagraph(TextMeasurer.java:444)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.TextMeasurer.measure(TextMeasurer.java:397)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillTextElement.chopTextElement(JRFillTextElement.java:1130)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillStaticText.prepare(JRFillStaticText.java:183)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillElementContainer.prepareElements(JRFillElementContainer.java:329)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillBand.fill(JRFillBand.java:419)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillBand.fill(JRFillBand.java:378)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillTitle(JRVerticalFiller.java:328)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReportStart(JRVerticalFiller.java:262)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReport(JRVerticalFiller.java:128)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:946)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:845)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.fillReport(JRFiller.java:58)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReport(JasperFillManager.java:417)
at com.netbyte.toby.aucklandzoo.server.dao.impl.ReportDaoImpl.createPDFJasperPrint(ReportDaoImpl.java:174)
at com.netbyte.toby.aucklandzoo.server.dao.impl.ReportDaoImpl.createReport(ReportDaoImpl.java:97)
at com.netbyte.toby.aucklandzoo.server.service.impl.ReportServiceImpl.createReport(ReportServiceImpl.java:23)
at com.netbyte.toby.aucklandzoo.server.gwtService.GwtReportServiceImpl.generateReport(GwtReportServiceImpl.java:25)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPC.java:561)
    ... 28 more
```

I already search in the web for the problem, I got a response that is related to the SDKs version 1.7 bug with font "Calibri" that I use in my reports, but the version of SDKs that I have on my server is 1.6 and I tested changing the font to a default one like "Arial", but when I tried again I get same error. The jasper reports version I'm using is 4.1.3.

Comment: Are you running code on `*nix` or on *Windows*?

Comment: on *nix, specifically on Gentoo distribution.